# \[\033[0;33m\] color code is showing up as plain text in man pages

Tags: colors, man

I'm seeing the string `\[\033[0;33m\]` show up at the begging of several lines in my `man` pages.

`\[\033[0;33m\]` is a shell color coding string that corresponds to yellow. So, for some reason instead of changing the color of the text to yellow, it's displaying as text in the `man` page. How can I fix this such that `\[\033[0;33m\]` is removed from my `man` pages?

[image: Color code issue example]

Comment: Can you clarify your question please?  Right now its a little ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @DavidVandenbos I've tried to clarify the question a bit. Is there something specifically that is unclear?

Comment: That looks better, it was just a little unclear on first reading. Thanks for taking the time to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by duplicated color variable entries that were both being exported.

```
export ORANGE="\[\033[0;33m\]"
export YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
```

Changing this to simply `export YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"` fixed the issue.